# Можно ли использовать это поле в IDE Delphi для своих целей?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В инспекторе объектов имеется поле, похожее на многострочное, которое тупо копирует название свойств при навигации, т.е. оно абсолютно бесполезно. Что ещё хуже, его даже нельзя скрыть!

Хотелось бы в своём проекте показывать там краткое описание свойства, но я так и не нашёл никакой информации, как можно изменять то, что там отображается. Возможно ли это и если да, то как?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Обновление, про DescriptionPane:

за работу с панелью DescriptionPane отвечает интерфейс `IPropertyDescription`, реализующий единственный метод: `function GetDescription: string;`

Если включить в созданный редактор свойства реализацию этого интерфейса, то своё описание будет появляться в этой панели при выделении свойства.

Пример, на основе того же VirtualTreeView:

```
TCheckImageKindProperty = class(TEnumProperty,... IPropertyDescription)
  public
    ...
    function GetDescription: string;
  end;

function TCheckImageKindProperty.GetDescription: string;
begin
  Result:='TCheckImageKindProperty.GetDescription';
end;
//====================
RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TCheckImageKind), nil, '', TCheckImageKindProperty);
```

[image: Результат]

### Про панельку рядом с DescriptionPane - HotCommands:

За работу с этой панелью (и за контекстное меню при клике по компоненту) отвечает `TComponentEditor`, а именно - его методы

`function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; virtual;
function GetVerbCount: Integer; virtual;
procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); virtual;`

Перекрыв их в своем зарегистрированном редакторе для компонента можно не только показывать информацию, но и выполнять необходимые действия.
Для примера я взял VirtualTreeView и изменил его редактор

```
type
  TVirtualTreeEditor = class (TDefaultEditor)
  public
    procedure Edit; override;  // этот метод был
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override; // остальные - добавил
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
  end;

procedure TVirtualTreeEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('Verb '+IntToStr(Index));
end;

function TVirtualTreeEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  if Index = 0 then
    Result:='VT action';
end;

function TVirtualTreeEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result:=1;
end;
```

И пересобрал дизайн-пакет компонента.

[image: в инспекторе объектов]

[image: при клике по нему]

[image: контекстное меню]

Comment: Почти. Это соседняя панель THotCommands. В неё дублируются кликабельные ссылки из popup-меню компонента, когда мы их добавляем в TComponentEditor. Она находится чуть выше, чем TDescriptionPane и прячется, если дополнительные пункты отсутствуют.
https://i.imgur.com/D37I8j5.png 
Туда не вывести информацию по текучему свойству, т.к. она общая для всего компонента

Comment: я думал в сторону аттрибутов 
https://habr.com/ru/post/105776/ 
возможно есть какой-то зарезервированный аттриут типа [Description('тут какое-то полезное описание')] для этой цели. Написал вчера в embracadero письмо, посмотрим ответят ли

Comment: Или какие-то "зарезервированные" конструкции, типа <summary>, которые исвользуются средой для показа всплывающих подсказок. (XML Documentation Comments)

Comment: @Isaev да, погорячился... пытаюсь вспомнить, где я видел именно то, что вы спрашиваете... ведь видел же :) И даже нашел, что нужно: IPropertyDescription - описание в DesignIntf именно то, что спрашивается

Comment: @Isaev обновил ответ. Теперь, вроде то :)

Comment: да, оно! Благодарю) Там в Designintf модуле много ещё интересного, главное было на него выйти.

Comment: техподдержка embarcadero ответила, что это невозможно сделать средствами Дельфи (только через Windows handle), панель осталась, как пережитки прошлого и больше не поддерживается... Вот так, не знают свой собственный продукт, что там можно, а что нельзя)

Answer (score 0):

Это не поле, а панель - `Status Bar`, на которой выводится системная информация. В данном случае информация о свойстве.

Незнаю есть такая возможность в ранних версиях или нет, но в более поздних версиях можно данную панель отключить, для этого нужно:

- Кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши на `Status Bar` (панель) или в окне `Object Inspecto'а`
- Выбрать пункт `Properties` (в результате откроется окно настроек `Status Bar'a`)
- Снять галочку с пункта `Show status bar'a` и нажать кнопку `Save`

Comment: Это не StatusBar, а TDescriptionPane... Само название даже напрашивается использовать её для описания свойств...
Но туда кроме как о свойстве/событии, точнее, даже не информация, а копирование его имени больше ничего никогда не выводится. Мы же можем дописывать свои редакторы свойств и редакторы компонентов, неужели нельзя достучаться до этой панельки?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что оно и создано, чтобы описание показывать, если описание не задано, то отображается имя. А вот где и каким образом оно задаётся, это вопрос... Может как-то через аттрибуты свойств или какие-то особые теги, типа documentation?

Comment: @Isaev `больше ничего никогда не выводится.` Выводится. К примеру, компоненты DevExpress размещают там даже кликабельные ссылки, по нажатию на которые открываются окна разных редакторов. Увы - как такое повторить - не знаю.

Comment: @kami, не совсем туда. И вы это прекрасно повторили в своём ответе)

Answer (score -2):

"Left" - нет (это вообще число и это поле активно используется по назначению - указывает смещение относительно родителя). Для краткого описания можно использовать Hint. При этом это поле может быть видимо конечному пользователю! Так же есть целочисленное свойство Tag, которое можно использовать по своему усмотрению.

Обзор свойств компонент: http://www.delphi.int.ru/articles/106/ - возможно тут найдется что-то для тебя полезное.

Comment: Этот ответ даже близко не в тему. Я не спрашивал про свойство Left